# Can we declare a variable of primitive type in aidl

Tags: android, aidl

I have one doubt. Can we declare a constant variable inside an aidl file?
For example, I have one aidl file named ITest.aidl:

```
package com.example.test;    
interface ITest {
   public static final String name = "abc";
   public static final int number = 1234;
}
```

as I tried my test application, it's giving a syntax error and runtime exception

```
Error:(4) syntax error
Error:(4) syntax error before ';' (expected method or constant declaration)
Error:(5) syntax error
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing 'D:\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aidl.exe' with arguments {-pD:\Android\sdk\platforms\android-25\framework.aidl -oE:\Workspace-Production\MyTestingApplication\app\build\generated\source\aidl\debug -IE:\Workspace-Production\MyTestingApplication\app\src\main\aidl -IE:\Workspace-Production\MyTestingApplication\app\src\debug\aidl -IE:\Workspace-Production\MyTestingApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\25.1.1\aidl -IE:\Workspace-Production\MyTestingApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\25.1.1\aidl -IE:\Workspace-Production\MyTestingApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-fragment\25.1.1\aidl -IE:\Workspace-Production\MyTestingApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-media-compat\25.1.1\aidl -IE:\Workspace-Production\MyTestingApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-core-ui\25.1.1\aidl -IE:\Workspace-Production\MyTestingApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-core-utils\25.1.1\aidl -IE:\Workspace-Production\MyTestingApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\animated-vector-drawable\25.1.1\aidl -IE:\Workspace-Production\MyTestingApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-vector-drawable\25.1.1\aidl -IE:\Workspace-Production\MyTestingApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-compat\25.1.1\aidl -dC:\Users\20065920\AppData\Local\Temp\aidl2875180729857776911.d E:\Workspace-Production\MyTestingApplication\app\src\main\aidl\ITest.aidl
```

Please refer me some link why it's behaving like this?

Answer (score 4):

AIDL supports methods and constant declarations.

You have to update the constant declaration at the aidl interface from,

```
package com.example.test;    
interface ITest {
   public static final String name = "abc";
   public static final int number = 1234;
}
```

to,

```
package com.example.test;    
interface ITest {
    const String NAME = "abc";
    const int NUMBER= 1234;
}
```

> String and int constants can be defined in the AIDL interface. 
>   For example: const int VERSION = 1;

Reference: [Create the .aidl file](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl#Create)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
const int number = 1234
```